# EF Core query - is there a way to find the next and previous item alphabetically?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, entity-framework-core, alphabetical

I have a list of things that I sort alphabetically. I am able to load this list using the following code:

```
model.Posters = this.NoTrackSet<Presentation>()
                    .OrderBy(v => v.Title)
                    .AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Now, in my UI, the user is allowed to click on one of these items to dig into the details of the object.

My task has been to add 'next' and 'previous' items on the details page, however I cannot figure out the SQL to find which item was previous, and which item was next.

I have considered loading the whole list twice and trying to figure out where I am and do an array forward / back by one, but it seems like there must be a more straightforward way of doing it. I need to get the prev and next item alphabetically by title.

To humor the SO gods, here is my current next / prev SQL code

```
Presentation prevPoster = this.NoTrackSet<Presentation>()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.PresentationTypeId == prs.PresentationTypeId                                                                                                          
                         && x.SessionId == prs.SessionId);

Presentation nextPoster = this.NoTrackSet<Presentation>()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.PresentationTypeId == prs.PresentationTypeId                                  
                         && x.SessionId == prs.SessionId);
```

It obviously doesn't work right.

Comment: If you already have the sorted list loaded, you should use that instead of another database query.

Comment: Its on another page load. CRUD.  I don't have it.

Comment: What type is your primary key of and of how many records are we talking about? An easy way would be to select all ids ordered by title. But that only makes sense manageable number of records in that table

Comment: it is going to be very slow keep fetching all the records each time user clicks next/prev just to sort them. use the ID and just take one record prev to that or next to that or buffer depending on how many records this is it might be best approach just load x number in the first place and only need to go back to database of longer and user wants go deeper, say load 20 in the first instance

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

previous:

```
db.Set<Presentation>()
  .Where(x => x.Title < currentTitle)
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Title)
  .FirstOrDefault()
```

next:

```
db.Set<Presentation>()
  .Where(x => x.Title > currentTitle)
  .OrderBy(x => x.Title)
  .FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with one query

```
var myList = db.Set<Presentation>().OrderBy(x => x.Title ).ToList();

int index = myList.FindIndex(a => a.Title == currentTitle);

var previous = index > 1 ? myList[index - 1] : null;

var next = index < myList.Count() ? myList[index + 1] : null;
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense for an unknown number of records. Simply calling ToList() will get all the data into memory.